# For loops and conditionals in Python

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

I am new to Python and I was wondering if there was a way I could shorten/optimise the below loops:

```
for breakdown in data_breakdown:
    for data_source in data_source_ids:
       for camera in camera_ids:
           if (camera.get("id") == data_source.get("parent_id")) and (data_source.get("id") == breakdown.get('parent_id')):
               for res in result:
                   if res.get("camera_id") == camera.get("id"):
                       res.get('data').update({breakdown.get('name'): breakdown.get('total')})
```

I tried this oneliner, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
res.get('data').update({breakdown.get('name'): breakdown.get('total')}) for camera in camera_ids if (camera.get("id") == data_source.get("parent_id")) and (data_source.get("id") == breakdown.get('parent_id'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` to handle the nested loops for you, and I think (although I'm not sure because I can't see your data) you can skip all the `.get` and `.update` and just use the `[]` operator:

```
from itertools import product

for b, d, c in product(data_breakdown, data_source_ids, camera_ids):
    if c["id"] != d["parent_id"] or d["id"] != b["parent_id"]:
        continue
    for res in result:
        if res["camera_id"] == c["id"]:
            res['data'][b['name']] = b['total']
```

Comment: Hi Sam! I tweaked a bit, using itertools and now it works. Code below:
for b, d, c in product(data_breakdown, data_source_ids, camera_ids):
    if c["id"] == d["parent_id"] and d["id"] == b["parent_id"]:
        for res in result:
            if res["camera_id"] == c["id"]:
                res['data'][b['name']] = b['total']
thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If anything, to optimize the *performance* of those loops, you should make them longer and more nested, with the `data_source.get("id") == breakdown.get('parent_id')` happening outside of the `camera` loop.

But there is perhaps an alternative, where you could change the structure of your data so that you don't need to loop nearly as much to find matching ID values. Convert each of your current lists (of dicts) into a single dict with its keys equal to the `'id'` value you'll be trying to match in that loop, and the value being whole dict.

```
sources_dict = {source.get("id"): source for source in data_source_ids}
cameras_dict = {camera.get("id"): camera for camera in camera_ids}
results_dict = {res.get("camera_id"): res for res in result}
```

Now the whole loop only needs one level:

```
for breakdown in data_breakdown:
    source = sources_dict[breakdown["parent_id"]]
    camera = cameras_dict[source["parent_id"]]
    res = results_dict[camera["id"]]
    res.data[breakdown["name"]] = breakdown["total"]
```

This code assumes that all the lookups with `get` in your current code were going to succeed in getting a value. You weren't actually checking if any of the values you were getting from a `get` call was `None`, so there probably wasn't much benefit to it.

I'd further note that it's not clear if the `camera` loop in your original code was at all necessary. You might have been able to skip it and just directly compare `data_source['parent_id']` against `res['camera_id']` without comparing them both to a `camera['id']` in between. In my updated version, that would translate to leaving out the creation of the `cameras_dict` and just directly indexing `results_dict` with `source["parent_id"]` rather than indexing to find `camera` first.

Comment: that works perfectly and with better performance! also, you are right about the camera loop. thank you!